# Find an example of a function f such that Lim(h->0) [f(c+h)-f(c-h)]/2h = L but f'(c)≠L?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, derivatives

I know that the limit defined in the question is actually just defined as f'(c) for some c. But this confuses me because if that limit exists, I believe f'(c) should also exist. Yet, how do we get these two to be different?

Comment: Try something non-continuous: $f(x)=0$ everywhere except at say $x=0$, with $f(0)=1$.

Comment: Ah, so is the question only asking for one value of c and not all c in the domain of f?

Comment: We are here on the internet, not in the MS-DOS world. At least avoid titles in cave dwellers' typography.

Comment: Or a continuous example such as $f(x) = |x|$ at $x =0$.